VBA Code (Copying and Pasting from one Excel Spreadsheet to another without the use of formulae)
I have included the screenshots of the spreadsheets below. I know basically nothing about VBA code so I require a bit of help in order to solve the problem.
So in workbook 1, on Cell L15 we have a calculated % DT (Downtime) Due to Engineering column which is calculated using FILTER and SUM functions.
It would be great if I could get this figure pulled through weekly into Column C of Workbook 2, starting with Cell C175 being this current week (Week 16). When the number in Cell D15 is refreshed weekly I would like it to add the new number over into the Column C (Week 17, 18....).
So far from a little help from other forums I have receieved the code (below), which only copies the values in the C column when the cells on B have been filled and it will only work for the last value of B.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A28:C315")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim desWS As Worksheet, x As Long
    Set desWS = Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsx").Sheets("Update 2023 & 2024 ENG % DT")
    x = desWS.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row-1
    desWS.Range("C" & x) = Range("L15").Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Thanks for the help,
Joel
I have tried the above code and don't know where to go from there
Workbook 1:

Workbook 2:

Workbook 1 (A28:C315 - Daily Report Log):

Workbook 1 (Updated Column):


You currently only copy the value in Range("L15"). It would be useful for you to include sample data as a table or a screencap as many people will not download files from unknown sources. Additionally, one those links go dead, the question becomes useless to future users of S.O.

Does this answer your question? How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

Your first screenshot doesn't include the source range A28:C315 ?

@TimWilliams I have included a screenshot of a section of the range. It is just a daily report log of any downtime and what department caused the downtime

Try this out - it will match on week+year
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim destWS As Worksheet, m, wk, yr
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A28:C315")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set destWS = Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsx").Worksheets("Update 2023 & 2024 ENG % DT")
    wk = Me.Range("B4").Value
    yr = Year(Date)
    
    m = destWS.Evaluate ("MATCH(" & wk & "&" & yr & ",A:A&B:B,0)") 'match week+year
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then                                 'got a match?
        destWS.Cells(m, "C").Value = Me.Range("L15").Value 'fill the value
    Else
        MsgBox "No match for week=" & wk & " year=" & yr & " !", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub



That worked well. However it is updating a cell above as there are multiple Week 17's due from 2021-2024 with 2021 updating. I was thinking about adding a column with the Year and was wondering how I would update the code in order to check also for the year and link it to B5 of Workbook 1. I have added an updated image above

Will the code use the current year to find the correct row?

See edits above for how to match on both values

Thanks for the help. That works as I wanted it to. Hopefully I learned a bit in the process.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim destWS As Worksheet, m, wk, yr

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, Range("A28:C315")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set destWS = Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsx").Worksheets("Update 2023 & 2024 ENG % DT")
wk = Me.Range("B4").Value
yr = Me.Range("B5").Value
m = destWS.Evaluate("=MATCH(""wk" & "yr"",A1:A200&B1:B200,0)") 'find the week number in ColA
If Not IsError(m) Then                                 'got a match?
    destWS.Cells(m, "D").Value = Me.Range("L15").Value 'fill the value
Else
    MsgBox "No week number match for '" & wk & "' !", vbExclamation
End If

End Sub
I've tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. However when I change it to this it does:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim destWS As Worksheet, m, wk, yr

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, Range("A28:C315")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set destWS = Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsx").Worksheets("Update 2023 & 2024 ENG % DT")

m = destWS.Evaluate("=MATCH(""17" & "2024"",A1:A200&B1:B200,0)") 'find the week number in ColA
If Not IsError(m) Then                                 'got a match?
    destWS.Cells(m, "D").Value = Me.Range("L15").Value 'fill the value
Else
    MsgBox "No week number match for '" & wk & "' !", vbExclamation
End If

End Sub

I am getting any error 2042 which I have seen in another page, however have tried both variant and double on the suggested parameters. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526784/why-am-i-getting-error-2042-in-vba-match)
